# Is there a way to get the logs of the entire chatbot conversation in Google Dialogflow to Firebase Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, dialogflow-es, chatbot, inline-editor

I've checked a few codes which help me capture only the values of the specific intents.

I have already linked the Dialogflow with the Firebase Realtime Database

How do I update the INLINE EDITOR - Code in the fulfillment tab of the Google Dialogflow to get the entire chatbot conversation into the Firebase Database?

Regards,

TIA

Answer (score 0):

In order to store the logs directly into Firebase, I would suggest that you checked [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs). This way, you will be able to capture the actions that you would like to capture.

If, on the other hand, you would like to capture all the logs from your Dialogflow agent, I would suggest that you used the [Audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/audit-logging) to capture them in Cloud Logging and then you linked Cloud Logging to Firebase following [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9748636?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

My understanding of Firebase is limited, but that documentation should point you on the right track!